# how to write a makefile in linux for a c program

Tags: c, linux, makefile

i have written a c program for doubly-linked-list in linux. the program is named as program2.c.
i have compiled it using "cc program2.c -o out2".
it compiled and also executed fine.

even also tried writing a makefile.my makefiel includes

```
all:doublelinkedlist
doublelinkedlist:program2.c
        gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -o $@  $<
clean :
        \rm -fr doublelinkedlist
```

when i did make it gives me the errors.
can any one please help me writing a makefile.

Comment: Show the errors you get.

Comment: I used your makefile as written, substituting a tab for the spaces before the lines gcc and \rm. It worked for me.

Comment: Oh, and don't use `-fr` when `-f` would suffice.

Comment: Why not follow the convention of having a program built from a single source file have the same name as the base name of the source?  So, either the program is `program2` built from `program2.c`, or the program is `doublelinkedlist` built from `doublelinkedlist.c`.  If you do that, you don't need a `makefile`; `make` knows how to build your program without any extra information.

Answer (score 1):

When using a makefile, you also started using the `-Wall -Werror` flags. This is a **very good** thing. 
Now the compiler looks for more suspicious things in your program, and refuses to compile if it finds anything. This can be a great help in catching bugs.

However, these warnings mean your program doesn't compile, and you'll need to fix them, by changing the code so that the compiler will be sure all is OK (as far as the compiler can check - of course the code can still contain bugs).

Common issues are mixing different types and not paying attention to the `const` keyword. But for help with specific warnings, you'll need to show the warnings and the code. Or better - search for each of them in StackOverflow, and I'm sure you'll find good answers.